# Center widget within space available in row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Please assist in how to create a layout like this, icon on left and text centered within available space left.

[image]

I have tried every time of Centering and Alignment I could think of. But I end up with nothing working, e.g.

[image]

Some of the code I've tried:

```
            Row(
//                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
//                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
//                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
//                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  buttonIcon,
                  Text(
                    buttonTitle,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `ListTile` widget instead of a `Row` one and achieve a very similar result, like this:

```
ListTile(
  title: Text('NAVIGATE HERE', style: TextStyle(....// your text style)),
  leading: Icon(Icons.some_icon)
)
```

If you still wish to use `Row` widget, you can achieve this using an `Expanded` widget as part of it's children, for example:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget> [
    Padding(
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: someValue),
     child: Icon(Icons.some_icon)
    ),
    Expanded(
     Align(
      alignment:Alignment.center,
      child: Text('NAVIGATE HERE')
     )
    )
  ]
)
```

Comment: Wrapping Align widget with padding right may give a better centered text.

Comment: The ListTile though a clever idea, didn't work as needed. The other example did however, with one change needed. child needed before the Align. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, border: Border.all(color: color, width: 2)),
  height: 56,
  width: 300,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.navigation),
        ),
      ),
      Align(child: Text("NAVIGATE HERE")),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: I was concerned about using a stack, cause the child widgets can go over one another, especially with long text. But is a working example so thank you! Below answer is better with that consideration, will mark it as the correct answer.